# Allow Users To Customize Their Profile URL

Tags: php, url, web, custom-url

I'm trying to allow users to create their own custom URL for their profile page.  I have a profile page called user.php that takes the parameter uid, so a URL might look like `http://website.com/user.php?uid=10`.  How would I assign that user their own url, for example `http://website.com/johndoe`?  And, additionally, how would I allow them to customize their URL if they feel the need to change it?

I planned on having a column in my MySQL table for `url` so that's where I plan to store this custom link.

Comment: create rewrite rule  in .htaccess

Comment: In just flat PHP? Or are you using a Framework?

Comment: It's flat PHP dwhite, and I'm not too skilled in managing the .htaccess file so I would have no idea where to start, dev